# Powershell command to open WSL session, connect to a remote machine then invoke a script on that machine

Tags: powershell, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I know I can use PowerShell to create a connection to remote machine, but for (company) reasons that I can't quite work out I need to connect to it via a *nix machine. That's ok though, because for the purposes of this the WSL system is fine.

I can work out how to run a single command via WSL from a PowerShell script -
`scp -i ~/.ssh/my_prv_key file.zip ec2-user@2.2.2.2:/home/ec2-user/`
for example works fine.

But what I then want to do is to connect to the remote machine, navigate to a different folder, log in as root, run a script... But I can't work out how to drive that from the PowerShell script.
From a *nix session I'd run:
`ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_prv_key ec2-user@2.2.2.2`
Then on the remote connection (for example):

```
cd /root/scripts
./do_something_with_uploaded_file.sh /home/ec2-user/file.zip
etc...
```

I'm assuming I'd do something like `WSL ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_prv_key ec2-user@2.2.2.2` but that doesn't seem to work - it's connecting, because it shows the last login time, but then what? The PowerShell session seems to just wait and wait.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up, if you are having an issue with `wsl ssh` seeming to hang, but it does seem to be connecting, it could be a pseudo-terminal allocation issue.  Try `wsl ssh -t ...` or `wsl ssh -tt ...` and see if that resolves that particular problem.

For the rest of your question, though ...

While you *could* install PowerShell on the remote Linux host and use PowerShell remoting, as @ralf-htp proposes, I think that's a bit overkill for just wanting to run a command on an EC2 instance, as you seem to be doing.  It may also not even be possible, since those EC2 instances appear to be company-owned, and you may not have the flexibility to add PowerShell to each of them.  But if that works, it's something to consider.

> for (company) reasons that I can't quite work out I need to connect to it via a *nix machine.

That's a bit weird.  Are you sure that you can't use OpenSSH on PowerShell?  It's a built-in feature that just has to be [turned on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse#installing-openssh-with-powershell).  You can then just use the `ssh` command directly from PowerShell, without going through WSL.  It seems unlikely to me that the remote would be able to know the difference.

> I can't work out how to drive that from the PowerShell script. From a *nix session I'd run: ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_prv_key ec2-user@2.2.2.2 Then on the remote connection (for example)

That's a bit of an apples-and-oranges comparison, it seems.  The example you give on "from *nix" is *interactive*, not scripting.  But on PowerShell, you say you want to drive it from a PS script.

The "scripting" answer is really the same either way when accessing a remote host via `ssh`.  You typically would put *all* the commands that you want to run directly on the `ssh` commandline.  Something like:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/my_prv_key ec2-user@2.2.2.2 "cd /root/scripts `; ./do_something_with_uploaded_file.sh /home/ec2-user/file.zip `; etc"
```

You quote the commands that you want to run on the remote host, separated by semicolons, quoted with the backquote (`` ` ``) to allow PowerShell to pass the semicolons through to the remote host.

The second option would be to `scp` a script file over to the remote system and then execute it using a similar `ssh "command"` syntax.  This would potentially alleviate some quoting issues if the script/command list is long and complicated.

I'd propose that Ansible might be a better fit here, but it seems that you *need* PowerShell for some reason.  It's still possible to access PowerShell commands from Ansible when running inside a WSL instance, and I've done it.  The main problem is that you start getting into nested quoting/escaping issues again that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can install PowerShell on any Unix/Linux system

**https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux?view=powershell-7.1**

From this machine you can proceed as usual when remoting-in using powershell. For a tutorial see this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qvJRaYlxI1w - *PowerShell Remoting*

See also **https://www.thomasmaurer.ch/2019/04/setup-powershell-ssh-remoting-in-powershell-6/**